# Call restfull webservice from android application

Tags: java, android, web-services, restful-authentication

Please support me !

Webservice (jersey restful):

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String login(
        @QueryParam("name") String name,
        @QueryParam("password") String password) {
    System.out.println("[login] name: " + name);
    System.out.println("[login] password: " + password);
}
```

Android app:

```
StringRequest insertRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.BASE_URL + login, new Response.Listener<String>() {
// ...
 @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("password", pass);
            return params;
        }
@Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
```

In server i received name and password is null. What is happend ?

Comment: I using postman call webservice => OK

Answer (score 0):

`@QueryParam` is not to be used with json, it is in the URI part. for example `users/query?from=100&to=200&orderBy=age&orderBy=name`, query params for this URI would be `from`, `to`, `orderBy`.

To use json, you will need to do Object Mapper against incoming JSON or accept the input as String and convert it to json.

Here is an example: [JSON example with Jersey + Jackson](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/)

Code for self convert to json **(Using Gson)** Maven Repository to [GSON](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson)

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String login(String jsonData) {
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject o = parser.parse(jsonData).getAsJsonObject();
}
```

The reason your postman works might be because you are actually sending a `x-www-form-urlencoded` 
[image]

Comment: :(, I still do not understand. How should the server be repaired?

Comment: I have posted a sample code using Gson to convert string to JsonObject. Although this requires external dependency

Comment: If you really want to use QueryParam, you can change on the android app to send form `x-www-form-urlencoded` and response json.
If you find this answer helpful please mark it as Accepted so next visitors can quickly locate it.